# Does existence of independent variables ensure that there are infinitely many solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

As I stated above. In a system of equations, does existence of independent variables ensure that there are infinitely many solutions?

THANK YOU!

Comment: And please also tell me why.

Comment: Be more specific, please. Examples, etc.

Comment: But the general rule is, either there is no solution, one solution, or infinitely many solutions. You have to consider the case of "no solution."

Comment: For example a matrix Ax=b. x_i is an independent variable. Does this mean there are infinitely many solutions? I mean if x_i is independent, it can be infinitely many numbers, so there will be infinitely many solutions following this logic. But Im not very sure im right.

Comment: That is not an example.

Comment: This Question is poorly phrased.  You are apparently asking about the solution of a linear system, and most likely what you mean by "independent variable" is sometimes called (in Gaussian elimination or *row reduction*) a variable without a corresponding leading one in any row.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean independent variable as to mean the same as my $t$ in the following example:

Say we a system of equations

\begin{align}
-x_1-2x_2-5x_3&=-3 \\
2x_1+3x_2+8x_3&=4 \\
2x_1+6x_2+14x_3&=10 \\
\end{align}

which we write on matrix form and then reduce:

\begin{align}
\pmatrix{
-1 & -2 & -5 & -3 \\
2 & 3 & 8 & 4 \\
2 & 6 & 14 & 10
} \rightarrow 
\pmatrix{
1 & 2 & 5 & 3 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
}
\end{align}

which is the same as

\begin{align}
x_1+2x_2+5x_3&=3 \\
x_2+2x_3&=2
\end{align}

Since we have two equations with three variables, we have a free parameter, which we define as $t=x_3 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Parameterization gives us that the full solution can be written as
$$\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3}=\pmatrix{-1 \\2 \\ 0} +t\pmatrix{-1 \\ -2 \\ 1}$$

which indeed represents an infinite number of points and therefore solutions.

Comment: @barbarossa1190 Was this was you meant?